# PHP in PHP, Problem with dynamic forms

Tags: php, forms, function, dynamic, input

I'm a newbee
I've got a little problem with my php-script. I try to generate dynamic formulars with php. which works very good. the problem is, I want my data to be send to another funcion in another php-script. I gues its a problem with the syntax:

```
<?php .... <form action=\"<?php myfunction() ?>\" ... > ... ?>
```

When I used it in a normal html site, it works fine:

```
<html> .... <form action="<?php myfunction() ?>" ... > ... </html>
```

So I'm lokking for a way to bring it in my php-script.

when I try this:

```
<?php .... <form action=\"" . myfunction() . "\" ... > ... ?>
```

the value won't be given to my 2nd php script

hope u have an idea, thank u guys, mirrow

Comment: give a better example or explanation, it's hard to guess what exactly you mean

Comment: please give the myfunction body

Comment: what do you mean with: "<html> <form action="<?php myfunction() ?>"  > </html>  " **works fine**?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass form data to function in another script, you must just call that script from the form:

```
<form action="secondscript.php">
```

And find a way to call your function, like:

secondscript.php:

```
...
    if ( isset( $_GET['somefield'] ) ) myfunction();

    function myfunction()
    {
    // do something with form data
    }
...
```

Comment: I find this much better, it separates concerns clearly and even helps analytics systems

Answer (score 1):

I believe, what you want is impossible! You can't send form data directly to a php function.

You need something like this:

```
<form action="receiving.php" method="post"><!-- or method="get" -->
  <!-- your form code -->
</form>
```

Than you need the php of the name in the action attribute:

```
<?php
function your_form_processing_function($_POST) { // or $_GET
  // process data
}
?>
```

Comment: ok I get it work with a little bit of all you guy advice, so thank you very much. but now I've a little other proble: I would like to save the url to a pic, a user can upload, in my database via a form. how do i have to wirte the POST variable for this

I have this input field.

input name=\"bildb\"  type=\"file\" /

and a form-tag

how do I get the file-url?

Answer (score 0):

a form's action determines the URL to which the form's data is sent to.
if you want to send your data to another page, the action field should be a path to that php page. if you want it to go to the same page, you can add a hidden field describing what function to go to, and send it to a page that routes the form to the given function based on that field.

Comment: i need to give the values to that function, but as I said its in another .php, the thing wih the hidde field sounds like a good plan, unfortunately I have no idea how to do this. do you may have anexample?

Answer (score 0):

Use this format:

```
<?php
.....
?>

<form action="<?php myfunction() ?>">
...
...
</form>

<?php
....
?>
```